Lichess API member's communities
Is there a way of getting all the communities a certain member belongs to on Lichess?

You can use Teams of a player api endpoint:
https://lichess.org/api/team/of/{username}
For example:
https://lichess.org/api/team/of/thibault
Currently returns:
[
  {
    "id": "chessguessr",
    "name": "Chessguessr",
    "description": "Chessguessr is a game where you try to guess the next moves in a chessgame. A new position is posted every day at midnight UTC, and most of the games are taken from Lichess!\r\n\r\nPlay the game on [Chessguessr.com](https://chessguessr.com).\r\n\r\nCode [on Github](https://github.com/Assios/chessguessr).",
    "open": true,
    "leader": {
      "name": "Assios",
      "title": "LM",
      "flair": "activity.xmas-lichess-horsey",
      "patron": true,
      "id": "assios"
    },
    "nbMembers": 235,
    "leaders": [
      {
        "name": "Assios",
        "title": "LM",
        "flair": "activity.xmas-lichess-horsey",
        "patron": true,
        "id": "assios"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "coders",
    "name": "Coders",
    "description": "If you want to join the team, prove (briefly) that you can code in the request message!",
    "open": false,
    "leader": {
      "name": "thibault",
      "flair": "symbols.rainbow-flag",
      "patron": true,
      "id": "thibault"
    },
    "nbMembers": 425,
    "flair": "objects.hammer-and-wrench",
    "leaders": [
      {
        "name": "thibault",
        "flair": "symbols.rainbow-flag",
        "patron": true,
        "id": "thibault"
      }
    ]
  },
...
]

